# Matching VSCode extension, to the filetype group of all programming languages

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have an extension for VSCode that dynamically modifies code (something like prettier).

I have set the extension to work on every file opened in VSCode.

The problem is that the markdown file, txt file, no stub - are also modified by my extension.
I do not want to list every existing programming language to match filetype, as supportedLanguages.

Question: What is the rule for supportedLanguages: allProgrammingLanguages? Such a group would exclude markdown, txt, etc.

Comment: just activate with `*` and analyze the languageID of the editor to see if it is an ID you want to process, yaml,cvs,feature,... are also no programming languages

Comment: I would like to have such an array variable in VSCode with all programming languages that updates itself and is either available from a library or built into VSCode. So that I don't have to manually add to it when I come across a new language.

Comment: what would be the advantage for VSC that somebody keeps track of ALL the file formats that are available and has to judge it is a programming language, then **What is a programming language**?, you can always let the user set the language IDs he wants to apply the extension

Comment: As the user will have an additional group variable, the user will have more options. That's what an option is supposed to do. I currently use *, and you can output a long list. And so it would be possible to type in a variable and problem solved.
It seems to me that you could perhaps make many such groups and use them for purposes other than mine.